# Kotlin error connecting to Postgres : org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail

Tags: postgresql, kotlin

I'm trying to connect my mobile app to the Postgresql server(using PgAdmin) but it's not working and give this error. I've tried using a lot of form of url in my code but it won't do.

```
val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres"
    val user = ""
    val password = "password"

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
    val db: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
    db.close();
```

I think my url is wrong. How do I fix that ?

PgAdmin DB :

[image]

Error :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codemobiles.project_eva/com.codemobiles.project_eva.FeedActivity}: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.`

THANKS!!!

Comment: Which driver version are you using?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid creating tables with upper case names https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: It's org.postgresql.Driver https://jdbc.postgresql.org. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: But which **version** of the driver? 42.2.x? Something else?

Comment: it's ver 42.2.12

Answer (score 0):

Sol : I quit using this jdbc and use the api from server instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error Driver version 42.2.23, when I try with ItelliJ everything's is fine!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).